# Flutter TwoDimensional Scrolling doesn't "stop" when tapped

Tags: flutter, user-interface, scroll

Flutter 3.13 has awesome new diagonal scrolling behavior and 2 dimensional scrolling. There's just not much info about it yet.

When I run this on an iPhone, I cannot get the scrolling to stop with a tap. Also, I cannot accelerate the scrolling as expected in most applications.

I also would like to add a scroll controller but doesn't seem this has the option. Any insight or solution appreciated. Thanks

```
// Copyright (c) 2019, the Dart project authors.  Please see the AUTHORS file
// for details. All rights reserved. Use of this source code is governed by a
// BSD-style license that can be found in the LICENSE file.

import 'dart:math' as math;

import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/gestures.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: Colors.deepPurple),
        useMaterial3: true,
      ),
      scrollBehavior: const MaterialScrollBehavior().copyWith(
        // Mouse dragging enabled for this demo
        dragDevices: PointerDeviceKind.values.toSet(),
      ),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  final String title;

  const MyHomePage({
    Key? key,
    required this.title,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text(title)),
      body: TwoDimensionalGridView(
        diagonalDragBehavior: DiagonalDragBehavior.free,
        delegate: TwoDimensionalChildBuilderDelegate(
            maxXIndex: 999,
            maxYIndex: 999,
            builder: (BuildContext context, ChildVicinity vicinity) {
              return Container(
                color: vicinity.xIndex.isEven && vicinity.yIndex.isEven
                    ? Colors.amber[50]
                    : (vicinity.xIndex.isOdd && vicinity.yIndex.isOdd
                        ? Colors.purple[50]
                        : null),
                height: 200,
                width: 200,
                child: Center(
                    child: Text(
                        'Row ${vicinity.xIndex}: Column ${vicinity.yIndex}')),
              );
            }),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class TwoDimensionalGridView extends TwoDimensionalScrollView {
  const TwoDimensionalGridView({
    super.key,
    super.primary,
    super.mainAxis = Axis.vertical,
    super.verticalDetails = const ScrollableDetails.vertical(),
    super.horizontalDetails = const ScrollableDetails.horizontal(),
    required TwoDimensionalChildBuilderDelegate delegate,
    super.cacheExtent,
    super.diagonalDragBehavior = DiagonalDragBehavior.none,
    super.dragStartBehavior = DragStartBehavior.start,
    super.keyboardDismissBehavior = ScrollViewKeyboardDismissBehavior.manual,
    super.clipBehavior = Clip.hardEdge,
  }) : super(delegate: delegate);

  @override
  Widget buildViewport(BuildContext context, ViewportOffset verticalOffset,
      ViewportOffset horizontalOffset) {
    return SimpleBuilderTableViewport(
      horizontalOffset: horizontalOffset,
      horizontalAxisDirection: horizontalDetails.direction,
      verticalOffset: verticalOffset,
      verticalAxisDirection: verticalDetails.direction,
      mainAxis: mainAxis,
      delegate: delegate as TwoDimensionalChildBuilderDelegate,
      cacheExtent: cacheExtent,
      clipBehavior: clipBehavior,
    );
  }
}

class SimpleBuilderTableViewport extends TwoDimensionalViewport {
  const SimpleBuilderTableViewport({
    super.key,
    required super.verticalOffset,
    required super.verticalAxisDirection,
    required super.horizontalOffset,
    required super.horizontalAxisDirection,
    required TwoDimensionalChildBuilderDelegate super.delegate,
    required super.mainAxis,
    super.cacheExtent,
    super.clipBehavior = Clip.hardEdge,
  });

  @override
  RenderTwoDimensionalViewport createRenderObject(BuildContext context) {
    return RenderSimpleBuilderTableViewport(
      horizontalOffset: horizontalOffset,
      horizontalAxisDirection: horizontalAxisDirection,
      verticalOffset: verticalOffset,
      verticalAxisDirection: verticalAxisDirection,
      mainAxis: mainAxis,
      delegate: delegate as TwoDimensionalChildBuilderDelegate,
      childManager: context as TwoDimensionalChildManager,
      cacheExtent: cacheExtent,
      clipBehavior: clipBehavior,
    );
  }

  @override
  void updateRenderObject(
      BuildContext context, RenderSimpleBuilderTableViewport renderObject) {
    renderObject
      ..horizontalOffset = horizontalOffset
      ..horizontalAxisDirection = horizontalAxisDirection
      ..verticalOffset = verticalOffset
      ..verticalAxisDirection = verticalAxisDirection
      ..mainAxis = mainAxis
      ..delegate = delegate
      ..cacheExtent = cacheExtent
      ..clipBehavior = clipBehavior;
  }
}

class RenderSimpleBuilderTableViewport extends RenderTwoDimensionalViewport {
  RenderSimpleBuilderTableViewport({
    required super.horizontalOffset,
    required super.horizontalAxisDirection,
    required super.verticalOffset,
    required super.verticalAxisDirection,
    required TwoDimensionalChildBuilderDelegate delegate,
    required super.mainAxis,
    required super.childManager,
    super.cacheExtent,
    super.clipBehavior = Clip.hardEdge,
  }) : super(delegate: delegate);

  @override
  void layoutChildSequence() {
    final double horizontalPixels = horizontalOffset.pixels;
    final double verticalPixels = verticalOffset.pixels;
    final double viewportWidth = viewportDimension.width + cacheExtent;
    final double viewportHeight = viewportDimension.height + cacheExtent;
    final TwoDimensionalChildBuilderDelegate builderDelegate =
        delegate as TwoDimensionalChildBuilderDelegate;

    final int maxRowIndex;
    final int maxColumnIndex;
    maxRowIndex = builderDelegate.maxYIndex!;
    maxColumnIndex = builderDelegate.maxXIndex!;

    final int leadingColumn = math.max((horizontalPixels / 200).floor(), 0);
    final int leadingRow = math.max((verticalPixels / 200).floor(), 0);
    final int trailingColumn = math.min(
      ((horizontalPixels + viewportWidth) / 200).ceil(),
      maxColumnIndex,
    );
    final int trailingRow = math.min(
      ((verticalPixels + viewportHeight) / 200).ceil(),
      maxRowIndex,
    );

    double xLayoutOffset = (leadingColumn * 200) - horizontalOffset.pixels;
    for (int column = leadingColumn; column <= trailingColumn; column++) {
      double yLayoutOffset = (leadingRow * 200) - verticalOffset.pixels;
      for (int row = leadingRow; row <= trailingRow; row++) {
        final ChildVicinity vicinity =
            ChildVicinity(xIndex: column, yIndex: row);
        final RenderBox child = buildOrObtainChildFor(vicinity)!;
        child.layout(constraints.tighten(width: 200.0, height: 200.0));

        // Subclasses only need to set the normalized layout offset. The super
        // class adjusts for reversed axes.
        parentDataOf(child).layoutOffset = Offset(xLayoutOffset, yLayoutOffset);
        yLayoutOffset += 200;
      }
      xLayoutOffset += 200;
    }
    final double verticalExtent = 200 * (maxRowIndex + 1);
    verticalOffset.applyContentDimensions(
      0.0,
      clampDouble(
          verticalExtent - viewportDimension.height, 0.0, double.infinity),
    );
    final double horizontalExtent = 200 * (maxColumnIndex + 1);
    horizontalOffset.applyContentDimensions(
      0.0,
      clampDouble(
          horizontalExtent - viewportDimension.width, 0.0, double.infinity),
    );
    // Super class handles garbage collection too!
  }
}
```